# hyperref bookmarksnumbered prefix or suffix

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf, bookmarks

Is there a way to modify the `bookmarksnumbered` option of hyperref to add a prefix and/or suffix to the section numbers?  The option currently changes the bookmark `Introduction` to `1 Introduction`, but I was hoping to achieve something like `C1 - Introduction`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting a modified `\thechapter` command just before the bookmark writing operation works (at least for a small document).

(Most likely the \let...` statement is necessary. I'll check later on)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\let\origthechapter\thechapter

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\addcontentsline}{%
\Hy@writebookmark{\csname the#2\endcsname}%
      {#3}%
      {\@currentHref}%
      {\Hy@toclevel}%
      {#1}%
}{%
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{C\origthechapter}
\Hy@writebookmark{\csname the#2\endcsname}%
{#3}%
{\@currentHref}%
{\Hy@toclevel}%
{#1}%
\endgroup
}{\typeout{Success}}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Other One}
\chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]