# Bookmarks numbering

Tags: numbering, bookmarks

I'm having trouble with `section` numbering.

I get things like:

1. Chapter 1

   PD11.1 Section 1.1

   PD11.2 Section 1.2

Example:

[image]

I want to remove this "PD1" before the section name.

Piece of code I am using:

```
\usepackage[unicode, pdftex, pdfpagelabels, bookmarks, hyperindex, hyperfigures]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,       
    bookmarksnumbered=true,      
    bookmarksopen=true,       
    colorlinks=true,        
    linkcolor=black,       
    citecolor=black,         
    filecolor=black,        
    urlcolor=black
}
```

EDIT:
Apparently, the problem was this piece of code:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
        % Make \section use text figures
        \let\myTheSection\thesection
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{\oldstylenums{\myTheSection}}
        % Make \subsection withou number
        %\let\myTheSubSection\thesubsection
        %\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
        % Make the page numbers in text figures
        \let\myThePage\thepage
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{\oldstylenums{\myThePage}}
}
```

I commented this out and the numbers are showing as expected!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal, but complete example? We can't say where this `PDI` come from at the moment!

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of this question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207843/hyperref-bookmarksnumbered-prefix-or-suffix, so it's related but no duplicate. Apparently the section counter format has been changed

Comment: Is there anything like `\renewcommand{\thesection}{PD1\thechapter.\arabic{section}}` in the code? If yes, this is most likely the culprit

Comment: No, I have this:    `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}`

Comment: @izzylp: Well, you should use a fully working document, not just a fragment

Comment: Ok, sorry, I thought maybe the problem would be easier to solve. I will try to do a minimal example and see how it works.